# Show the float value in formatted string two digits after decimal in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, numbers

I have a float number in which i insert comma after thousands value it works fine

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // this line is important!

NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:appDelegate.C_WND_ClinInf_Average_Default]];
```

but it shows 1,947 but i want it to show 1,947.00 any idea how to formate like this.

Thanks

Comment: @Tendulkar not working this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using -setMaximumFractionDigits from NSNumberFormatter?

So, try something like:

```
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
```

This way you deal with NSNumberFormatter only and don't need to call anything extra on NSString.

Answer (score 6):

simple write

```
NSString *myNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", yourFlotNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // this line is important!

        NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:appDelegate.C_WND_ClinInf_Average_Default]];


  NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",yourfloatno];
```

try this one .....

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code a bit...I don't think you need a number formatter.

```
float myNumber = appDelegate.C_WND_ClinInf_Average_Default;
NSString *myNumberAsText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",myNumber];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this one 
its work fine for me...

---

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];

```
[formatter setPositiveFormat:@",##,###.00"];
NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:no]];
```